# Need jQuery plugin to implement this UI

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know of a jQuery plugin to implement this UI?

http://img.skitch.com/20100930-rfngg5f7pqgssfgg2y4iyqm73s.jpg

Unfortunately I'm not able to find anything like that on Google.

You can write a script on JQuery, but I would not want to waste time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: btw, when someone posts the correct answer to your question, you should click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

[Multiselect](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) has a slightly different UI, but works on a similar principle.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the jQuery UI `Sortable` feature, which can be used to allow the user to drag items between lists; [two lists demo and documentation here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists). (I bet there's a clever way to combine [`Selectable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable) with this to make for an even better UI.) But you'd still want to have a fallback for non-JavaScript browsers.

**Update** [Here's a live example](http://jsbin.com/ubuvo3) of taking a boring old multi-`select` listbox and using progressive enhancement to turn it into two lists you can drag items between. Note that the example ensures that the original `select` box is kept up-to-date so that any form submission works as expected.